# Zend Studio - numbers of workspaces in List "Switch Workspace"

Tags: zend-studio

There is a list of 5 workspaces by [File/Switch workspace].
Where can I increase the number of available workspaces?

I know, there is a button to browse the whole filesystem, but it's troublesome.

I'm sure, there is a menu to change the option from 5 to 8(?), like in the Office-Apps, but I can't find.

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows\Préférences\General\Start & Shutdown\Workspaces : You can modify the number of recent workspaces to remember.

Check also for org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs file in the directory zend\configuration.settings...

Comment: Ah, it is a eclipse-option ... well hidden, I have wasted so much time searching. Thank you, it works!